# Swift IAP SKProduct wrong price displayed

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter, currency-formatting, skproduct

I use In App Purchases in an iOS app. I want to display the price in the right format depending on the user/device.

Here's my code:

```
let price=product.price

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFoxrmatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4   //doesn't change anything if I remove this line
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
numberFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale

let formattedPrice=numberFormatter.string(from: price)
```

But the currency symbol is not the good one and/or misplaced in some cases.
In my example, the price product is **$19.99** or **20,99€**.

---

Examples

**From device:**

`product.priceLocale`: `en_FR@currency=EUR (fixed)`

`Locale.current`: `en_FR (current)`

Output: €20,99

Should display: 20,99€

**From simulator:**

`product.priceLocale`: `en_FR@currency=EUR (fixed)`

`Locale.current`: `en_US (current)`

Output: $20.99

Should display: 20,99€ or $19.99

---

I have several users who have the same issue with other currencies where the symbol should be placed after the price, unlike the dollars format. And another user who sees **$7290 instead of 7290₸** (which is quite a different price...).

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the **language setting** or the `Locale.current`. But if I change my primary language to French on my device, I have the same price "€20,99". What is weird is my `Locale.current` switches to `en_US (current)`.

Any way to solve this?

Another solution I'd be happy with: **display the price in dollars for everyone**, whatever the user's language & currency.

Comment: The price (e.g. value) of the item is based on the country you are logged into in iTunes, not the locale. So if you are set up in iTunes (sandbox?) with an account from the US, you will see the US value

Comment: I think the best option is to display the `priceLocale.currencySymbol`. The symbol will be misplaced in some cases but at least it's the good price with the good currency.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
// localize to your grouping and decimal separator
currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.current

// We'll force unwrap with the !, if you've got defined data you may need more error checking
let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: 9999.99)!
print(priceString) // Displays $9,999.99 in the US locale
```

Example

```
currencyFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")
if let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: 9999.99) {
    print(priceString) // Displays 9 999,99 € in the French locale
}
```

For more detail please check https://supereasyapps.com/blog/2016/2/8/how-to-use-nsnumberformatter-in-swift-to-make-currency-numbers-easy-to-read

Comment: It didn't work. And I think `priceLocale` should be taken into account at some point to avoid mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

Locale setting is key to the correct output. en_FR reads like English language and french region. This will result in formatted output for an english speaker with french price -> €10.00

Use the simulator and set region & language to french and use Locale.current. It should read fr_FR and give correct output. 10,00€

Did you try to change language and region on the simulator and does it effect priceLocale?

Comment: I set the region & language to French on the simulator; priceLocale turns to `fr_FR@currency=EUR (fixed)` and I get 20,99 €. The problem is I can't ask my users to change their settings so I need to find a solution that works for everyone. From @KerrM comment's, I think I'll display the currency from priceLocale and that's it.

Comment: Why ask the users to change there preferred settings? I think it is correct to show different price formats by the user settings. Use of priceLocale will do the right thing for you.

Comment: I agree with Kai. This shouldn't be a problem -- what you described in your comment there looks like the expected behaviour.

Comment: I thought @Kai was asking me to change the settings (region & language).